# https doesnt work on react-native android

Tags: react-native, https, fetch, apisauce

When i try to get a request to my api via https protocol it doesnt work (NETWORK_ERROR returns), but if i do it via http it works fine. Im using apisauce. What i've tried:

- do request to https://my.api.url via postman - works fine
- do request    to http://my.api.url via postman - works fine
- do any requset to    https://my.api.url with fetch, axios, apisauce, or via web view - doesnt work (NETWORK_ERROR)
- do any requset to http://my.api.url with    fetch, axios, apisauce, or via web view - works fine (i had to make    edits
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to do so)
- do any requset to    https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 with fetch, axios, apisauce - works fine

I think the problem with certificates(?), but why i can do it via postman?
RN 0.64.0

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @SyedAmirAli no, even after installing a correct signed certificate on backend

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was wrong FQDM:
was:

```
api_demo_13312021.mydomian.com
```

changed to:

```
api.mydomain.com
```

I checked my domain for correct ssl sertificate on many resources, but they apparently don't check FQDM. Today i tried it on https://www.digicert.com/help/ and notified for

```
not a fully qualified public domain name or public IP address.
```